# JavaFX - Updating TableView content after an edit in another Controller

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I have two Controllers for two different FXML files, `AutoController` and `InsertAutoController`.
In `AutoController` I use a tableview that displays values taken from a database, and in `InsertAutoController` I have functions which insert or edit data and therefore change the database content.
The tableview in `AutoController`:

```
@FXML
private TableView<ModelAuto> autotable;
@FXML 
private TableColumn chilometraggio; 
@FXML 
private TableColumn modello; 
@FXML 
private TableColumn requisiti;
@FXML 
private TableColumn stato; 
@FXML 
private TableColumn targa; 
@FXML 
private TableColumn costokm; 
@FXML 
private TableColumn fascia;
```

The function I use to set the values taken from the database in `autotable`, is `loadTableAuto`:

```
    @FXML
void loadTableAuto()
{
    //Autovettura
    try {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>autof = (ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>) fc.processRequest("ReadModelAuto");
        ArrayList<ModelAuto> C = new ArrayList<ModelAuto>();
        for(int i=0; i<autof.size(); i++)
        {
            ModelAuto c1 = new ModelAuto(autof.get(i).get(0), autof.get(i).get(1), autof.get(i).get(2), autof.get(i).get(3), autof.get(i).get(4), autof.get(i).get(5), Double.parseDouble(autof.get(i).get(6))); 

            C.add(c1);
        }

        ObservableList<ModelAuto> clienteData = FXCollections.observableList(C);

        targa.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ModelAuto, String>("targa"));
        fascia.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ModelAuto, String>("fascia"));
        modello.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ModelAuto, String>("modello"));
        chilometraggio.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ModelAuto, String>("ultimokm"));
        requisiti.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ModelAuto, String>("requisiti"));
        costokm.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ModelAuto, Double>("costokm"));
        stato.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ModelAuto, String>("stato"));


        autotable.setItems(clienteData);

        } catch (SecurityException  | NoSuchMethodException
            | ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
            | IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

I call this function in the `initialize()` method.

I open the FXML of `InsertAutoController` as a window above the window of the `AutoController`, which stays open all the time. I don't know how can I call the function `loadTableAuto` when I close the `InsertAutoController` related window, so that the table can display the updated values.

I tried to import the `AutoController` class in `InsertAutoController` and to use the `loadTableAuto()` function in there but it gives me a NullPointerException error.
The function to insert new values in `InsertAutoController`:

```
    @FXML
private void handleOk(ActionEvent event) {
    if ((fasciacombo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() == null) || (modellocombo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() == null)  || (statocombo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() == null))
    {
        //alert message: incorrect values
    }

    else
    { 
       //values are correct
        try {
        boolean ok = (boolean)fc.processRequest("IAuto", reg); //function that inserts values in the database and returns boolean
        if (ok==true)
        {
            //I wanted to call the loadTableAuto() function in here, after I added data in the database, before the stage is closed
            Stage stage = (Stage) okbtn.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.close();
        }
    } catch (SecurityException | NoSuchMethodException | ClassNotFoundException
            | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }

    }
```

Is there a way to call this method somehow after I edit the database and close the window controlled by `InsertAutoController`?
Or a way to update the Tableview automatically when an edit is done?